# How Does Bone Knight's Paladin Conversion Interact with Paladin of Tyranny

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, optional-rules

I was wondering what rulings there are on how the Bone Knight's Paladin Conversion ability interacts with the Paladin of Tyranny? It would seem that the class had the PHB Paladin in mind during the creation of said ability. With that being said, if there are no official rulings on the mattsr, how would you rule on said matter?

Answer (score 6):

Variants are generally not fully developed rules, more akin to fairly comprehensive idea suggestions. You are always going to have to massage variants a bit more than other rules to get them to fit; supplements written after the variant, for example, will almost-never take that variant into account (though it may consider earlier supplemental material, and always considers core material).

So, for our paladin of tyranny bone knight...

> If you were a paladin or ex-paladin before becoming a bone knight

OK, so here’s the thing: the term “paladin” becomes somewhat ambiguous with the *Unearthed Arcana* variant.

- Is your class “paladin” with “tyranny” as your chosen path, à la a “wizard” who chooses the path of the “conjurer”?
- Or is your class “paladin of tyranny,” which despite obvious similarities to “paladin” is still a separate class?

*Unearthed Arcana* has this to say:

- > These paladin variants aren't meant to be unique classes in and of themselves, but rather alignment-based variations of the paladin.

This does rather imply that “paladin” does refer to you. Tellingly, it also suggests that

- > you might consider designating the standard paladin as the "paladin of honor" to differentiate it from the variants.

Furthermore, while below things do look weird for paladins of slaughter and tyranny, much of what is being said in bone knight about the paladin (of honor) also makes sense for paladins of freedom.

So OK, “if you were a paladin” appears to be true, so what next?

> you can never again advance levels as a paladin, since your association with the undead forever taints you

...but this makes limited sense, considering the paladin of tyranny’s undead-healing *deadly touch*. OK, sure, *inflict* is not the same as *animate dead*, and is not Evil... but the paladin of tyranny is. So this doesn’t make a lot of sense, but just for the sake of argument, where are they going with this?

> However, you retain (or regain) certain paladin abilities, including divine grace, lay on hands, aura of courage, divine health, and spellcasting. You cannot detect or smite evil or remove disease. [...] You lose the service of your special mount (but see the summon skeletal steed ability, below).

Well, some of these you have, the others you don’t but you have other features that each “otherwise functions identically to the paladin’s” version. Since *Unearthed Arcana* did not mention the bone knight, the “otherwise” here kicks in, and those features function “identically to the paladin’s” for the purposes of whether or not bone knight lets you use them.

> You can use your lay on hands ability to cure living or undead creatures.

As above, this applies to *deadly touch*, allowing it to cure living creatures (where ordinarily this would allow *lay on hands* to cure undead). Assuming you are not an ex-paladin of tyranny, you retain the ability to harm the living (just as a paladin of honor would retain the ability to harm the undead).

So, by this exceedingly-strict reading, you retain Divine Grace, *deadly touch*,  Aura of Despair, Divine Health, and spellcasting. Your *deadly touch* furthermore gains the ability to cure the living if you so choose. You lose both *detect good* and Smite Good, as well as *cause disease*, and your special mount is replaced by the skeletal steed.

But as mentioned from the very beginning, being strict is not particularly appropriate with variants: they require that the DM finesse them into the existing ruleset and setting. For example, personally, I think it would make no sense for the paladin of tyranny to lose the ability to progress that class, or to lose the various “evil-flavored” versions of things the paladin of honor loses. In fact, my recommendation for paladins of tyranny is that the only change that should come out of the Paladin Conversion feature is the addition of curing living creatures to *deadly touch*.